# Python with sparql-client - ImportError: cannot import name 'encodestring' from 'base64'

Tags: python, sparql

I am Python newbie. Trying to use this module https://pypi.org/project/sparql-client/

**module.py**

```
from sparql import Service


class MyModule:

    def my_method(self):
        s = Service('https://my-endpoint:8182/sparql', "utf-8", "GET")
        statement = """
            MOVE uri:temp_graph TO uri:user_graph
            ADD uri:temp_graph TO uri:user_graph    
        """.format(user_graph="http://aws.amazon.com/account-uid",
                   temp_graph="http://aws.amazon.com/account-uid-temp")
        s.query(statement)
```

I am trying to test it

**test_module.py**

```
import unittest

from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

class TestModule(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('sparql.Service', autospec=True)
    def test_mymethod(self, sparql_mock):
        sparql_instance = sparql_mock.return_value
        sparql_instance.query = Mock()
```

While running I get

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 1564, in <lambda>
    getter = lambda: _importer(target)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 1236, in _importer
    thing = __import__(import_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sparql.py", line 50, in <module>
    from base64 import encodestring
ImportError: cannot import name 'encodestring' from 'base64' (/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/base64.py)
```

So it can not import this line

https://github.com/eea/sparql-client/blob/master/sparql.py#L50

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have base64 module installed? Try installing the module. you seem to be running on linux so use pip command to install modules

Comment: @nelsonsule How to check whether I have it or not?

Comment: launch your python IDLE and run import base64. python is an interpreted language so if it throws an import error exception, then it means it is not installed. you can also check by attempting to install the module. if it is installed, it will throw an exception

Comment: @nelsonsule ok seems I have that module 
`
% python3
Python 3.9.0 (default, Oct 27 2020, 14:15:17)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.21)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import base64
>>>
`
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is caused by the version of `base64` module you are running while the version of `sparql` you have installed is dependent on a lower version of the `base64` module. The `sparql` is dependent on `base64` version built for python3.1. `encodestring()` and `decodestring()` have since been deprecated.

- Option 1 - Your best bet (if you must continue using this version of `sparql`) is to downgrade your version of python to 3.1 from 3.9 which is your current version.
- Option 2 - will be to adopt the new specifications for the current version of `base64` you have installed. this will mean updating `sparql` and anywhere you are calling deprecated methods of `base64`.

If you choose to go with option 2, then open the `sparql` module and edit the import statement. Change `from base64 import encodestring` to `from base64 import encodebytes` and replace any occurrences of `encodestring` with `encodebytes` in your code and any module you have dependent on `base64`. That should solve your problem.